# Unable to install Visual Studio Update 2 and Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-phone, parallels

I tried three times to install Visual Studio Update 2 but everytime i got this
[error](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v80aer19rdj8uzb/Screen%20Shot%202013-05-03%20at%206.20.37%20PM.png) at the end of Update 2 installation:

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 Assemblies.

Fatal error during installation.

I have installed only Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate and Windows Phone 8 SDK on a Parallels virtual machine.

Does anybody how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the Win Phone 8 SDK before installing update 2?

Comment: no because Microsoft said that the correct steps are: install VS, install the sdk and then install the update 2, as reported [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/31/windows-phone-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-2.aspx)